# How to access the values of a foreign key of another table using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I created a custom pivot model which is SectionSubject that have an id, section_id and subject_id. I want now to access the other values related to the section_id. Here is my Sectionsubject model and section_subject table:

SectionSubject.php

```
class SectionSubject extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'section_subject';

    public function students()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'section_subject_student','section_subject_id'
            )->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function assignStudents(Student $student)
    {
        return $this->students()->save($student);
    }

}
```

create_section_subject.php

```
Schema::create('section_subject', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('section_id')->unsigned();
  $table->integer('subject_id')->unsigned();
  $table->string('schedule')->unique();
  $table->string('room_no');

  $table->foreign('section_id')
     ->references('id')
     ->on('sections')
     ->onDelete('cascade');

  $table->foreign('subject_id')
     ->references('id')
     ->on('subjects')
     ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Now I want to fetch those values and place it on my ReservationController. I tried to use one to many relationship but it seems not working.

```
class ReservationController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $sectionSubject = SectionSubject::find(1);

        //code here
        return view('reservation.form', compact('sectionSubject');
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fetch relationship by doing this

```
$sectionSubject = SectionSubject::with('students')->find(1);

//print your variable
echo "<pre>";
 print_r($sectionSubject->toArray());
echo "</pre>";
```

you will find the related table data

Comment: thanks for your response. However please read fully the question. Thank you.

Comment: can you share your table structure, means which belongs to Pivot table, and which other data you want to access ?. Explain it little more, So I can update my answer according to that